# Creating asp.net membership tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, asp.net-membership

I am using Entity Framework code first, so keep dropping and re-creating the database.  My asp.net membership tables keep disappearing as well - particularly annoying on the build server.

The best way I have found to create the tables so far involves a post build event running aspnet_sql.exe, but the connection strings need to be hard-coded and its making staging-release environments difficult.

Is there an elegant way to create the tables in code?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you dropping and re-creating tables so often? Maybe migrations could solve this issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx). Then you don't need to use  aspnet_sql.exe.

Also use migrations rather than drop and re-create database.